How to plot stacked bar chat in the latest version of SHAP
I am trying to reproduce the following example with the latest version 0.46.0 of SHAP open source. However, it seems to be weird that the result is not a bar chat as in the example.

My attempt: Then, I tried to the library to find the summary_plot but could not find any information. I then tried to use shap.plots.bar but it resulted in this type of error. I hope you could help me perform the stacked bar plot as in the above link with the latest version.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[155], line 1
----> 1 shap.plots.bar(shap_values)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/shap/plots/_bar.py:83, in bar(shap_values, max_display, order, clustering, clustering_cutoff, show_data, ax, show)
     78 else:
     79     emsg = (
     80         "The shap_values argument must be an Explanation object, Cohorts "
     81         "object, or dictionary of Explanation objects!"
     82     )
---> 83     raise TypeError(emsg)
     85 # unpack our list of Explanation objects we need to plot
     86 cohort_labels = list(cohorts.keys())

TypeError: The shap_values argument must be an Explanation object, Cohorts object, or dictionary of Explanation objects!


Please [reprex]
